# Solving the system $\cos\phi=\sin\frac\theta2$ and $\sin\phi=-\cos\frac\theta2$ for $\phi$ yields contradictory solutions

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, angle

I solved a little trigonometric equation but it seems that my solution is false and I am trying to understand why as I think it's a very basic problem.

The aim is to try to find the value of the angle $\phi$ as a function of $\theta$ in the following system :

$$\cos(\phi) = \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$ and $$\sin(\phi) = -\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

I've simply noted that $\cos(\phi)$ can be written as : $$\cos(\phi) = -\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
and also :
$$\sin(\phi) = -\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Therefore, we end with an equation to solve which is $\tan(\phi) = \tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ giving : $$\phi = \frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$$

However, the correction of the problem points to the fact that $$\phi = \frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}$$ as they wrote :
$$\cos(\phi) = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
and also :
$$\sin(\phi) = -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

which seems also logic and correct..

My question is : why do this problem seems to have 2 different solutions ? $\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}$. What is the point that I am missing here ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: You noticed that $\phi$ contains a $k\pi$ term. What would happen if $k=-1$? Do you have any restrictions on $\phi$ and $\theta$?

Comment: @Andrei Yes sorry for not premising it but $\theta \in ]0;\pi[$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add the first two equations to get that $$\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)=\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)-\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)$$
We can combine the two trigonometric functions from each side to get $$\sqrt2\sin\left(\phi+\frac\pi4\right)=\sqrt2\sin\left(\frac\theta2-\frac\pi4\right)$$
Therefore we have $$\phi+\frac\pi4=\frac\theta2-\frac\pi4\Rightarrow\phi=\frac\theta2-\frac\pi2$$
or $$\phi+\frac\pi4=\pi-\left(\frac\theta2-\frac\pi4\right)\Rightarrow\phi=\pi-\frac\theta2$$
Although the $\pi-\frac\theta2$ solution is consistent with $\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)=\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)-\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)$, it is not consistent with $\cos(\phi)=\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)$ or $\sin(\phi)=-\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)$.

The only solution that works is $$\phi=\frac\theta2-\frac\pi2$$

Comment: @Mehta Thank you for your explanation but I still don't get why the answer $\theta = \frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}$ is still a valid solution ??

Comment: @Waxler If $\phi=\frac\theta2+\frac\pi2$ then $\cos\phi=-\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)$ and $\sin\phi=\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)$. You divided one equation by the other, but this added an extra solution, $\phi=\frac\theta2+\frac\pi2$, which doesn't satisfy either of those two equations.

Comment: @Mehta You are right : I have been confused by the sign... So to be sure again : the method was valid but obviously the result was not adequate with the original equations ? But we could have found the same result if we changed the values of $k$ in the general form of the solution $\phi = \frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$

Comment: Your method is valid, but you need to check your answers. Both mine and your method involved combining two equations, which means that we have both created a solution that itself is invalid. In my case, this was $\phi=\pi-\frac\theta2$. In your method, if $\cos\phi=-\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)$ and $\sin\phi=\cos\left(\frac\theta2\right)$, which is an invalid solution, $\phi$ still satisfies $\tan\phi=\tan\left(\frac\theta2+\frac\pi2\right)$, so you found this solution, which has misled you. You should find that for $\phi=\frac\theta2+\frac\pi2+k\pi$ to be a valid solution, $k$ must be odd.

Comment: @Mehta Thank you for your answer : I understand your comment it helps a lot Thanks !